# finding property with true flag in an object

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I have an object with three properties.

```
$scope.badges = {'Full Service': false, 'Negotiable': true, 'Under Warranty': false};
```

How do i `extract OR find property` from it with `true` flag?

Basically, i want to find property from this object having true flag and then assign it to another scope variable.

**My HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="(badge,enabled) in badges" class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="badges[badge]" /> {{badge}}
    </label>
</div>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.badges = {
    'Full Service History': false,
    'Negotiable': false,
    'Under Warranty': false,
    ' Urgent': false
};
```

**I want to see which checkbox user has selected.**

Comment: At what level is this occurring? In the controller? Service? Template? Any additional code or better yet a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co) or [codepen](http://codepen.io) would be greatly appreciated. Side note: be cautious whenever changing the scope directly; it's very easy to create "scope soup" or worse... angular digest issues.

Comment: @Dom, I updated my question. Hope it help you to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much cleaner solution:

```
$scope.activeKeys = [];
for (var key in $scope.badges) {
    if ($scope.badges[key]) {
        $scope.activeKeys.push(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks much cleaner solution.

Comment: It's almost exactly my answer. (:

Comment: this thing as a one-liner: `$scope.activeKeys = Object.keys($scope.badges).filter(k => $scope.badges[k])`

Comment: @Thomas As usual, functional always wins :p

Comment: Did i make something wrong in selecting the correct answer? I know the 'The F' answered very first and i am very thankful for that but the fact is i found @Bwaxxlo answer quite clean and short. I don't want to hurt anyone feelings. BTW, i upvoted every other answer. Thats the max justice i can do. Cheer guys.

Comment: @simbada It's ok. We're just being pretentious.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish what you want with this code in your controller:

```
$scope.trueFlags = [];
for(var prop in $scope.badges) {
  if($scope.badges.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop === true) {
    $scope.trueFlags.push(prop);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each property and check if its value is true:

```
$scope.badges = {'Full Sevrice': false, 'Negotiable': true, 'Under Warranty': false};
var keys = [];

for(var name in $scope.badges) 
    if ($scope.badges[name]) {
        keys.push(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer